# Excel VBA - Random Number Generator that check if number already exist (loop)

Tags: excel, vba

First I have no idea from programming but I need to do a Random Number Generator which check if this Number already was generated in the cell before. I hope someone can help me with some easy code.

My Idea:

I have 80 Cells all in a single line/row. I will start with the loop at Row 1 -> Generate Number -> Check if this number already exists above -> If not write it into the cell and do the same again in row 2 / if yes generate a new number -> check again

Many thanks!

Comment: https://www.exceltip.com/tips/random-numbers-generator-without-repeat.html

Comment: Depending on the number type and range it might be possible to do it in excel if you are not familiar with programming

Comment: @Kevin thank you! I tried it but i get on every cell 0 instead of a number

Comment: @Jayvee just normal type like 1, 2, 3 not 3,12 - Range is from 1 to 80

Comment: If you want to avoid VBA, you can generate a list from 1 to 80 and remove the existing numbers from Row 1, then pick random values from the resulting list using INDEX and RANDBETWEEN

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub KeineZufallszahlDublikate()
Dim intI As Integer, Zahl As Integer
Dim ZahlArray(200) As Boolean
Dim NoDups As New Collection
Dim Item As Variant

Dim cell As Integer
cell = Cells(1, 6).Value
Randomize
For intI = 1 To cell
Do
Zahl = Int((cell * Rnd) + 1)
Loop Until ZahlArray(Zahl) = False
ZahlArray(Zahl) = True
NoDups.Add Zahl
Next
For Each Item In NoDups
ActiveCell.Value = Item
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).